# Can I allow access to certain applications only in Remote Desktop connection?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-server

**Scenario : REMOTE DESKTOP CONNECTION**

I am using a Windows 8 pc to give access to certain applications in a small lab(15-20 computers). I want to restrict access to certain resources(Hard Drives,Windows Settings, Control Panel, regedit, run, gpedit etc...). Simultaneously I want to give access to 1 or 2 application/files only. Is this possible in any ways?

***N.B : I have researched about the gpedit settings but it does allow access to files whether it be in a hidden drive.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `regedit` settings, Inside which you can easily alter the machine settings :

- Allowing and Blocking access
- Change hardrive access settings
- Restrict Control Panel Settings, all similar administrative stuff.
  But remember it will restrict local access to.

So I would suggest you to design a small tool which accesses the remote resources through Shared Folders, this would most probably fit in your case.

Thanks!!